# Network Disabled on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet

On a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop with a Realtek RTL8822CE Wifi adapter, when I click on the Wifi icon, no Wifi networks show up. I've tried looking at other answers but they haven't helped me.

When I enter the command:

```
$ lshw -C network
```

I get:

```
 *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: c0:e4:34:48:52:cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-53-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:75 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f770ffff
```

and

```
$ iwconfig
```

output:

```
eno1      no wireless extensions.

enx00909e9dd05e  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

and

```
$ sudo rfkill list all
```

output

```
    0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Hey, I am facing the exact same problem, with the same adapter, but on Ubuntu 20.04. Did you manage to fix this somehow?

Comment: Also if it's still not resolved, could you please check the error you get on `dmesg`, when you turn on your Wifi, and append it to your answer?

Comment: Hey zean, I installed Ubuntu 20.0.4 on the same computer, and I did not face the same problem. I think the issue was with drivers, but I couldn't figure out how to get them installed.

Answer (score 3):

It is likely that the network-manager state got corrupted. Open the file `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state`. It should look something like this:

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Change any from `false` to `true` to re-enable networking. It may work better if you first stop NetworkManager:

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

And start it again once done.. Or reboot

This happened occasionally after wakeup in Lucid. In Maverick this should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install drivers for this adapter. Connect to internet by other means, e.g. your phone and run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple solution worked, I just enabled the NetworkManager using this command

```
systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to restart the network manager

```
sudo systemctl stop network-manager
sudo systemctl start network-manager
```