# WiFi not showing up on my Ubuntu 18.04 newly installed. My laptop is Asus tuf FX705 DT. I am a newbie, please help me out

Tags: 18.04, wireless, asus

WiFi not showing up on my Ubuntu 18.04 newly installed. My laptop is Asus tuf FX705 DT. I am a newbie, please help me out.

[image]

Comment: Your notebook is a bit too new for Ubuntu 18.04. You might be better served by 20.04 or 21.04 

Comment: You need to add the output of `lscpi -knn |grep Net -A3`.

Comment: @matigo I’m triple booting my system with windows, Ubuntu 20 which I have earlier and now Ubuntu 18. I have a necessity to run ROS melodic which won’t run in Ubuntu 20, that’s why

Answer (score 0):

These helped to resolve my issue, thanks very much!
https://askubuntu.com/a/1291415
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Comment: If that answer resolved your issue, then at least upvote it so that others can know that the answer is genuine and may have helped someone. :|

Comment: @zean_7        I don't have enough reputation to upvote, I'm a newbie :)